# PayPal Express Checkout issue

Tags: magento-1.6, paypal-express

I have been experiencing this weird issue the last 2 weeks, and it's happening very randomly.

---

- customers were using IE as the browser
- they put something in the shopping cart and clicked PayPal Express Checkout
- they were redirected to PayPal, logged in, and clicked to come back to my site to confirm the order
- then they saw an error message that says Unable to initialize Express Checkout (at this stage, this order actually got through, payment processed and Magento order created)
- thinking that the order did not get through, they retried, and failed, and finally gave up by using the normal PayPal checkout, which worked.
- they then saw duplicate payments in PayPal and sent me complaints

Could anyone please guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I am getting exactly the same issue.  Are you in the UK, as I think it is a PayPal UK problem.

I used to have a meta tag to make IE browsers later than IE8 to emulate IE8 browsers and never used to have these issues.  I can't work out whether its a recent change by PayPal or the removal of the emulation.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, it may have been better added as a comment to the original question.